# How to do smart upselling and cross-selling in Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2, ecommerce

I want to have the following features on my Craft Commerce site:

- Often bought together: Bundling
- You may also like: Upselling/cross-selling/personal recommendations
- Accessories

I realize that it's easy to define custom fields that let me associate products with each other - but I am not looking for a manual method.

I did a search on "ai powered cross selling ecommerce" and found a few stand alone solutions and some specifically tailored to e-commerce solutions like Magento.

But what would you do? Have any of you experiences with this kind of machine learning/ai algorithm for cross-selling/product recommendations/personalization?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe The purchase Patterns Plugin Could Solve your problem.

https://github.com/ethercreative/purchase-patterns/blob/v1/README.md